# dine on Crow - sitting down to a heaping helping of Crow

Tags: phrase-meaning

> GOP **dine on Crow** while Trump makes Catholic Bishops look Saintly
> Ohio GOP will be **sitting down to a heaping helping of Crow** tonight while Trump serves up a buffet of lies while continuing to cage children.

Source: Scott Adams on [Philadelphia PA's Patch site](https://patch.com/pennsylvania/philadelphia/gop-dine-crow-while-trump-makes-catholic-bishops-look-saintly)

What does "dine on Crow" mean? The word crow is capitalized and it seems to be an expensive restaurant, I am not sure. Considering the author said in text with "sitting down to a heaping helping of Crow", it seems to mean a luxurious activity - a festival. Wikipedia explains what is "eating crow" - "Eating crow is a colloquial idiom, used in some English-speaking countries, that means humiliation by admitting having been proven wrong after taking a ..." - yet the crow here is not capped. The best guess I have had now is that the crow can be either capitalized or not, the meaning is exactly what Wiki explains. I am not very sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading what is essentially an [op-ed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Op-ed), if that. I would be very surprised if it passed through any copy-editing process. See the note at the top of the post:

> This post was contributed by a community member. The views expressed here are the author's own.

It is not common to capitalize the word "crow" in the idiom "to eat crow" which means, as you have discovered, "to admit being wrong, usually in a humiliating way." It *could* be the case that there is some person called "Crow" mentioned in the post and the article is making a pun on their name; you can see that is not the case, so my guess is that the capitalization is a quirk on the part of the author.

"Dine on crow" and "sit down to a heaping helping of crow" are not established idioms in their own right—but they are recognizable as being fancier wordings of the standard idiom.